# Which startup file is being used by my shell?

Tags: bash

There are several startup files in my ubuntu installation on Google compute engine.

Is there any command that tells me which startup file is being used by the shell I am currently using?

Comment: Bash manual at your rescue: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html

Answer (score 4):

The list of files shells typically read on start-up is limited to only a few. But those in turn may *source* others, and that can end up being a large numbers like when complex completion systems are loaded.

An approach is to run your shell with:

```
strace -e open your-shell
```

(or the equivalent command on your system like `truss`/`tusc`/`dtruss`...)

That will list all the files the shell opens. That would also list files it opens and that are not startup files, and files that it attempts but fails to open though.

Another approach could be to use the `xtrace` mode of some shells where the shell outputs on stderr what it's going to do for each command. For that, you just call the shell with the `-x` option.

Some shells like `zsh` will print the paths of the file where the code being run comes from by default (though you may want to set `PS4` to `+%x>` for instance for the name of the file to also be printed for code run in functions). For some others like `bash` or `ksh93`, you can make it print it by modifying the `$PS4` variable.

```
PS4='+$BASH_SOURCE> ' bash -x
PS4='+${sh.file}> ' ksh93 -x
PS4='+%x> ' zsh -x
```

With `bash`, you can post-process the output so as to retain only unique paths of the files with something like:

```
PS4=' <:>$BASH_SOURCE<:>' BASH_XTRACEFD=3 3> >(
  awk -F'<:>' 'NF>2 && !seen[$2]++ {print $2}') bash -x
```

(assuming the paths of the startup files don't contain newlines or `<:>` and that there's no multi-line command being run in those startup file that contain `<:>`)

Those `xtrace`-based approaches won't list start-up files that are empty or consist only of comments or function definitions (unless those functions are being run later on), nor start-up files that the shell would process if they were there.

You can however retrieve the files from which functions have been defined with

```
eval "(shopt -s extdebug; declare() { typeset -F \"\$2\"; }
  $(typeset -F))" | cut -d ' ' -f 3- | sort -u
```

with `bash` or

```
type ${(k)functions} | sed -n 's/.*is a shell function from //p' | sort -u
```

with `zsh`.