# How to find out which files have defined "alias"es?

Tags: bash, alias, bashrc, profile

When I run the `alias` command, I see an alias which I don't know where it has been defined (i.e. I cannot find the file which contains definition of this alias). I have checked `/etc/profile`, `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `/etc/bash.bashrc` and some others but to no avail.

Is there a way to find out which files the `alias` command gets its info from? I mean how does the `alias` command work? Does it read some predetermined files looking for alias definitions?

Comment: The list of available aliases isn't defined in any specific place; it's the result of all of the `alias <name>=<definition>` commands that have been executed in that shell process since it started. Shells automatically run the commands in the various init scripts at startup (which files are run depends on how the which shell program it is, how it's started, etc). Those can run other scripts (with the `source` or `.` commands). You can also define aliases manually. To find out where a particular alias is coming from, you have to trace the shell startup process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Along the lines of [Stéphane's similar answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/367353/117549), here's a way to run an interactive bash shell in trace mode (running the single command `exit`), piped to a grep that shows only the `source` and `alias` commands; the `source` command immediately above the `alias` of interest should be the file that contains the alias command.

```
bash -ix -c exit 2>&1 | grep -E 'source | \. |alias '
```

An instrumented run:

```
$ tail -1 ~/.bashrc
[ -f /tmp/a.bashrc ] && source /tmp/a.bashrc
$ cat /tmp/a.bashrc
[ -f /tmp/b.bashrc ] && . /tmp/b.bashrc
$ cat /tmp/b.bashrc
alias answer='echo 42'

$ bash -ix -c exit 2>&1 | grep -E 'source | \. |alias '
+ alias 'ls=ls --color=auto'
+ source /tmp/a.bashrc
++ . /tmp/b.bashrc
+++ alias 'answer=echo 42'
```

Comment: For me, this command (`bash -ix ..`)  only shows the aliases, no source. I guess this is because `.` can be used instead of `source`.

Comment: Excellent point; I'll update the `grep` statement accordingly.

Comment: I like `PS4='  ${BASH_SOURCE}:$LINENO ' bash -lixc exit | grep ...` for debugging.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Thanks. I'm still having trouble finding the file. "the source command immediately above the alias of interest should be the file that contains the alias command." it seems this wasn't the case for me. I'll look more into it tomorrow and let u know.

Comment: Ok. I found the problem. The alias was set through `set-alias` command ([module environment](http://modules.sourceforge.net/c/modulefile.html)). When I ran your suggested command, in the output the path `/etc/profile.d/modules_environment.sh` which loads user-defined modules as well appeared 4 lines above the alias definition.