# Ctrl + c to clear input stopped working

Tags: bash, terminal, rhel

I have the habit of using `ctrl` + `c` as a quick way to clear the input field in the terminal. I'm working on a set of Red Hat servers where this suddenly stopped working. I tried canceling a `grep` command using it (which worked before), all I get is `^C` printed as a separate line, and the grep keeps working. There are cases where `ctrl` + `c` works, for instance stopping the `top` command.

On my Ubuntu machine hitting `ctrl` + `c` adds `^C` to the line, and then gives me a new and fresh line where I can type. On the RHEL servers, it does nothing.

I'm not sure where to start looking for an issue here, any pointers?

Output from `stty -a`

```
$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 23; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke
```

Update: Output from trap:

```
~$ trap
trap -- '' SIGINT
trap -- '' SIGQUIT
trap -- '' SIGTSTP
trap -- '' SIGTTIN
trap -- '' SIGTTOU
```

Comment: Is just Ctrl+C that does not work? Can you do a Ctrl+U to clear the line?

Comment: Ctrl + U clears what is written, without giving a new input line. So I guess that is as expected.

Comment: Yes, Ctrl-U just clears the line to the beginning. So it's just Ctrl-C which does not work. Try a `stty -a | grep intr`, it should be `intr = ^C`, it might got changed by a recent update.

Comment: What is the output of `stty -a` ?

Comment: Updated question with output from stty -a.

Comment: I might add that the servers _should_ not have been updated from what I know. We have a puppet config handling a subset of the servers, and it works on non-puppet servers, so I'm suspecting something might have gone wrong from that source.

Comment: try `trap - INT` to reset the `SIGINT` handler to default if it was set to ignore.

Comment: stty looks normal. I'd run `trap` to see if the shell has been set to ignore SIGINT, as @UncleBilly said.

Comment: The output of `stty` will be misleading here.  Your question needs to state what shell you are using.

Comment: I'm using `bash`, added the tag.

Comment: @UncleBilly That did the trick :D Do you know if there is a way to configure this on multiple servers, using puppet?

Comment: in Emacs Ctrl+U deletes to the left, Ctrl+K clears to the right and I often use them to clear the whole line. Some other useful shortcuts: Alt+F move forward one word, Alt+B move back one word, Ctrl+W delete word, Alt+D delete next word

Comment: The default for bash is to not catch or ignore SIGINT. You may have some init file that is doing `trap "" SIGINT`. See [Which startup file is being used by my shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/367322/which-startup-file-is-being-used-by-my-shell) to see if one of its init files has that `trap` line.

Comment: Ok, so one of your shell's startup files seems to set traps to _ignore_ specific signals for some reason. It may be your personal `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` (or similar) file, or one of the `/etc/*profile*` files.  See if you can find it and see if it's accompanied by some comment.

Comment: Would that be a command starting with `trap`?

Comment: @Tobb Yes, it would be a command involving the `trap` command.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the following did the trick:

`trap - INT`

Comment: So, what installed an `INT` trap in you shell?

Comment: I have no idea :(

Comment: If it was a trap, what was it? What does the `trap` command by itself output (before you removed the trap with the command in your answer)?  (I'm only trying to pry some extra information out from you to make the answer more useful for others with similar issues.  At the moment, it's "I had _this_ issue, and _this_ solved it", but it lacks a _because_ part that would not only show why the answer solved the issue but why the issue was there in the first place).

Comment: Started a new session against the same server, and the problem was back. Might be because the session where I fixed it is still active. Anyways, added output from trap to my question

Comment: Problem seems to reappear when I open a new session. Difference in trap output before and after running the command is that this goes away: `trap -- '' SIGINT`. Don't know why it appears in the first place though.