# Customized Linux systems cannot use crtl+c to terminate ping commands?

Tags: linux, shell, busybox, stty

I customized the root file system using `Busybox`， and its version is `1.36.1`. I don't know why my device cannot be terminated by `ctrl+c` when typing `ping` an IP on the monitor keyboard. However, when I connect to the device through SSH, the `ping` an IP can be terminated by `ctrl+c`? The same goes for `ctrl+u`.

I referred to [similar problems](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/497479/ctrl-c-to-clear-input-stopped-working), but did not solve my problem.

By the way, my system does not have a desktop environment. My processor is Intel x86_64 bit.

#1
#stty -a (SSH connection)

```
speed 38400 baud; rows 41; columns 143; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^H; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z;
rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc ixany -imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc
```

#stty -a (monitor keyboard)

```
speed 38400 baud; rows 37; columns 100; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl -ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany -imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
-isig -icanon -iexten -echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc
```

#2
#cat /etc/inittab   (old)

```
::sysinit:/etc/init.d/rcS
::respawn:-/bin/sh
::ctrlaltdel:/bin/umount -a -r
::shutdown:/bin/umount -a -r
::shutdown:/sbin/swapoff -a
```

#cat /etc/inittab  （new）

```
::sysinit:/etc/init.d/rcS
tty1::respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty1
tty2::respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty2
tty3::respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty3
tty4::respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty4
tty5::respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty5
tty6::respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty6
::ctrlaltdel:/bin/umount -a -r
::shutdown:/bin/umount -a -r
::shutdown:/sbin/swapoff -a
```

#3
#echo $SHELL (SSH connection)

```
/bin/bash
```

#echo $SHELL (monitor keyboard)

```
/bin/sh
```

#4
#echo $TERM (SSH connection)

```
xterm
```

#echo $TERM (monitor keyboard)

```
xterm
```

#5
#tty (SSH connection)

```
/dev/pts/0
```

#tty (monitor keyboard)

```
/dev/console
```

#6
#ls -l /dev/console /dev/tty[0-9]

```
crw-rw----    1 root     root        5,   1 Jan  4 04:31 /dev/console
crw-rw----    1 root     root        4,   0 Jan  4 04:31 /dev/tty0
crw-rw----    1 root     root        4,   1 Jan  4 04:32 /dev/tty1
crw-rw----    1 root     root        4,   2 Jan  4 04:31 /dev/tty2
crw-rw----    1 root     root        4,   3 Jan  4 04:31 /dev/tty3
crw-rw----    1 root     root        4,   4 Jan  4 04:31 /dev/tty4
crw-rw----    1 root     root        4,   5 Jan  4 04:31 /dev/tty5
crw-rw----    1 root     root        4,   6 Jan  4 04:31 /dev/tty6
crw-rw----    1 root     root        4,   7 Jan  4 04:31 /dev/tty7
crw-rw----    1 root     root        4,   8 Jan  4 04:31 /dev/tty8
crw-rw----    1 root     root        4,   9 Jan  4 04:31 /dev/tty9
```

Comment: This question could benefit from more clear wording, especially in the first two sentences. For example, what does "customize the root file system using Busybox", "device cannot be terminated" and "ping an IP" mean? There are also some missing relevant details, such as how is the shell started, what shell is used? What is the contents of the `TERM` environment variable and so on? Lastly, if it was compiled from source, Busybox can be configured quite extensively during compilation.

Comment: @Vilinkameni `ping` is a linux command，`ping an IP` means that the IP can be any.

Comment: Is the `stty -a` output from the SSH connection or from the session on monitor keyboard? Try `stty -a` on both, and see if there are any differences. In particular, check that `intr = ^C` is listed in both cases.

Comment: @telcoM I added the results of `stty -a` obtained from the screen, but they all have `intr = ^C`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the "monitor keyboard" `stty -a` output, there is `-isig -icanon -iexten`, while the SSH session has these features enabled (no `-` sign in the front).

And the `man stty` describes these as follows:

> `[-]icanon`
> enable special characters: erase, kill, werase, rprnt
>
> `[-]iexten`
> enable non-POSIX special characters
>
> `[-]isig`
> enable interrupt, quit, and suspend special characters

So, with `-isig`, the Control-C, Control-\ and Control-Z special functions are **switched off**. Likewise, `-icanon` indicates the `erase`, `kill`, `werase` and `rprnt` functions won't take effect either. You can fix this with `stty isig icanon` on the monitor keyboard session.

This might be because you are starting `/bin/sh` directly in `/etc/inittab` without using something like a `getty` process to initialize the TTY device settings to well-known values at the beginning of the login process.

If you want to run a shell directly from `inittab` without a login requirement, you should do any necessary TTY initialization yourself in `/etc/init.d/rcS`, for example:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6; do
    stty -F /dev/tty$i isig icanon
done
```

On a SSH session, pseudo-TTY devices (PTYs for short) are used, and `sshd` takes care of their initialization automatically.

`/dev/console` as the result of the `tty` command output is a bit suspicious. On the x86 architecture at least, the `/dev/console` is essentially a compatibility alias for whatever is the currently active console device: it might normally connect to `/dev/tty0` (i.e. the currently-active KVM virtual console) but it might point to a serial port like `/dev/ttyS0` if a `console=` kernel boot option was used.

Does your kernel have all the following configuration options enabled?

- `CONFIG_VT_CONSOLE=y`
- `CONFIG_HW_CONSOLE=y`
- `CONFIG_VT_HW_CONSOLE_BINDING=y`
- either `CONFIG_VGA_CONSOLE=y` or `CONFIG_FRAMEBUFFER_CONSOLE=y` and an appropriate framebuffer console driver, like `CONFIG_FB_VESA=y` for classic BIOS or `CONFIG_FB_EFI=y` for UEFI, and/or maybe also `CONFIG_DRM_FBDEV_EMULATION=y` if using newer Direct Rendering GPU drivers on the console.

Are the console device nodes set up correctly? On a Debian 12 system, `ls -l /dev/console /dev/tty[0-9]` has the following output:

```
crw--w---- 1 root tty 5, 1 Nov 10 02:26 /dev/console
crw--w---- 1 root tty 4, 0 Nov 10 02:25 /dev/tty0
crw--w---- 1 root tty 4, 1 Jan 30 13:37 /dev/tty1
crw--w---- 1 root tty 4, 2 Nov 10 02:25 /dev/tty2
crw--w---- 1 root tty 4, 3 Nov 10 02:25 /dev/tty3
crw--w---- 1 root tty 4, 4 Nov 10 02:25 /dev/tty4
crw--w---- 1 root tty 4, 5 Nov 10 02:25 /dev/tty5
crw--w---- 1 root tty 4, 6 Nov 10 02:25 /dev/tty6
crw--w---- 1 root tty 4, 7 Nov 10 02:26 /dev/tty7
crw--w---- 1 root tty 4, 8 Nov 10 02:25 /dev/tty8
crw--w---- 1 root tty 4, 9 Nov 10 02:25 /dev/tty9
```

The permissions and ownerships may vary according to current logins & how your distribution chooses to handle them, but the major/minor device numbers (the two digits separated by comma and whitespace) should be exactly like this.

Comment: When running `stty isig`, error `stty:standard input:cannot perform all requested operations` is prompted. Is there any way to do this? I added the same in `rcS`

Comment: If you run the command `tty` on the monitor keyboard, what does it output?

Comment: One example of a working _/etc/inittab_ which uses OpenRC and Busybox is from Alpine Linux, from the package [alpine-baselayout-data](https://git.alpinelinux.org/aports/tree/main/alpine-baselayout/inittab). It uses *getty*: `tty1::respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty1` (repeated for _tty1_ through _tty6_) and so on. In Alpine, `stty -a` gives `isig icanon`, both in terminal emulators and console.

Comment: @Vilinkameni I tried it and the result was the same.

Comment: @telcoM All the kernel options you mentioned are `Y`.

Comment: @telcoM When I started with the new `inittab`, the result of `tty` was `/dev/tty1`, but it is still `-isig` and does not support settings, and the error reported is the same.

Comment: @telcoM After comparison, it should be the same.

Comment: @telcoM When I started the system with the new `inittab`, I switched to `tty2` using `ctrl+alt+f2`. I could use `ctrl+c`. However, when I specified `console=tty2` to start in `grub.cfg`, there was still a problem. After switching to `tty3` using the same method, I was able to use `ctrl+c`.