# How do I know what config files are being read by my bash shell?

Tags: bash, macos, rc

I'm on a macOS system. My `SHELL` variable says `/bin/bash`, but I have Homebrew `bash` installed too.

I deleted my `.bash_profile` file, and my `.bashrc` only sets the `PATH`. But now every time I type <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a new tab in `Terminal.app`, something echoes the word `foo` just before I'm given my prompt. I grepped around in `/etc` and found nothing, but since this is a Mac things might just be arranged differently.

Is there a way to know which config files are being read in when I start up a shell? Where should I look?

Comment: Linking in https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/334382/117549

Comment: LOL, the contents of my ~/.profile said "echo foo". Nevertheless, the question is still a valid one I think.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find out what scripts are being run by bash on startup](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/334382/find-out-what-scripts-are-being-run-by-bash-on-startup)

Comment: see [How to determine where an environment variable came from?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/813/170373) and [Which startup file is being used by my shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/367322/170373). You didn't ask about envvars, but that first one contains an answer that shows _everything_ the shell runs, file names included.